# Anything known about the Grundy Ordinal of Sylver's Coinage

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, ordinal-numbers, nim

[Sylver's coinage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylver_coinage) is an example of an unbounded finite (if slightly modified) combinatorial impartial game. Quoth wikipedia:

> The two players take turns naming positive integers that are not the
> sum of nonnegative multiples of previously named integers. After 1 is
> named, all positive integers can be expressed in this way: 1 = 1, 2 =
> 1 + 1, 3 = 1 + 1 + 1, etc., ending the game. The player who named 1
> loses.*

This can be made to have the normal play convention if we make $1$ an illegal move.

In Conway's ONAG, it is shown that Grundy's number can be generalized to ordinal numbers for unbounded impartial games.

**Is anything known about Grundy's ordinal for Sylver's Coinage and its various positions?**

<sub>*Wikipedia contributors. "Sylver coinage." Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, 21 Oct. 2014. Web. 27 Mar. 2015.</sub>

Comment: I seem to remember this cropping up in one of the Games Of No Chance collections, but I'll have to dig around for it a bit.  AFAIK the value of the initial position is unknown and no position is known to have value $\geq \omega+\omega$ (there _are_ positions known to have value $\omega$ and I believe there are some with value $\omega+n$ for various $n$), but don't hold me to either of those.

Comment: It's my impression that explicitly finding the ordinals even for finite positions of Sylver Coinage is a very difficult question; even an explicit (impractical) recipe to decide whether an infinite position has ordinal value 0 would be a major advance in our knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

One thing we do know about the Grundy number of a position is that it is less than or equal to the ordinal representing the maximum length of the game starting from that position; to be precise, define $\ell(p)$ to be 0 if the position $p$ is an ending position, and

$$
\ell(p) = \sup_{q \in p}\{\ell(q)+1 \}
$$

otherwise. (by $q \in p$ I mean that from position $p$ the acting player can move to position $q$)  Then the Grundy number $G(p) \le \ell(p)$.

For Sylver Coinage, $\ell(p)$ is rather easy to determine. $\ell$ of the starting position is $\omega^2$; for any other position, the players will have selected some nonzero finite set of positive integers.  Let $d$ be the GCD of all the numbers in the set, and let $m$ be the number of (not necessarily distinct) primes dividing $d$.  Let $n$ be the number of possible next moves that are divisible by $d$.  Then $\ell(p) = \omega m + n$.  The Grundy number must be less than or equal to this ordinal.

Comment: The condition for 0 is unnecessary as sup{}=0.

Comment: I prefer to keep it for clarity.